# What does double (*fptr)() mean in parameter list for trapezoidal rule function?

Tags: c

I am wondering as to why `double (*fptr)()` is used in the parameter list of  a trapezoidal rule function??

I know it means file pointer of a double. But why do i neet the empty brackets?

Comment: "file pointer of a double" doesn't even remotely make sense...

Answer (score 4):

You may want to try [http://cdecl.org/](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=double+%28*fptr%29%28%29) for such question:

> C gibberish ↔ English
>
> ```
> double (*fptr)()
> ```
>
> declare fptr as pointer to function returning double

Answer (score 3):

It does not mean file pointer to double, the f stands for *function*.

This becomes obvious once you look at how functions are defined:

```
double myfunc()
```

If I now want a pointer to a function that takes no arguments and returns a double it would be of type

```
double (*)()
```

which is the type of your parameter. Adding a name (`fptr`) to it results in the following:

```
double (*fptr)()
```

is a parameter named `fptr` (short for function pointer) which is a pointer to a function that takes no arguments and returns a double.

Answer (score 1):

Its not file pointer, declaration `double (*fptr)()` means `fptr` is **pointer to function** that returns a `double` and takes no argument,(*empty bracket means pointer to function*)

An example: Suppose you have a function like:

```
double fun(){
  double d = 0.9;
  return d; 
}
```

then you can assign address of `fun` to `fptr` like:

```
fptr = fun;
```

you can call `fun()` using `fptr` like:

```
d = fptr()
```

Where `d` is some double variable

**Edit**
I feel you need to know  [Pointers To Functions](http://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/int/sx10.html), in general, we defined function pointers like:

```
returntype function (argtype1, argtype2, argtype3)
```

A corresponding pointer to such a function is

```
returntype (*ptr) (atgtype1, atgtype2, atgtype3);
```

Notice here is no empty brackets but I use type of arguments, where your `fptr` points to a function like I given in example that doesn't accept argument.